# How can I do an ssh tunnel with port forwarding on a Windows runner in Github actions?

Tags: github-actions, google-compute-engine, portforwarding, windows-server

I have a MongoDB instance on a Google compute engine running that I want to connect to from my Github action (On a windows runner if it makes a difference) to insert test and performance results.

Currently, I am trying to open an SSH tunnel with port forwarding and just test that the port is open.

Here is what my GIthub action step is:

```
- name: 'Create ssh tunnel'
  if: (runner.os == 'Windows')
  run: |       
    gcloud config set auth/impersonate_service_account *****@***.iam.gserviceaccount.com
    gcloud compute config-ssh

    $sshTunnelJob = Start-Job -Name SshTunnelJob -ScriptBlock { ssh -o "User=*****_iam_gserviceaccount_com" *****.us-east1-b.**** -vvv -fNT -L 27017:0.0.0.0:27017}

    Get-Job 
    Receive-Job -Name SshTunnelJob | Format-List -Force -Expand CoreOnly

    netstat -aon

    Test-NetConnection localhost -port 27017
    
    gcloud config unset auth/impersonate_service_account
    gcloud compute config-ssh --remove
```

I expect this, `Test-NetConnection localhost -port 27017`, to succeed, but it fails. Forwarding port 80 is succeeding, though.

Here is the output:

```
WARNING: TCP connect to (::1 : 27017) failed 
WARNING: TCP connect to (127.0.0.1 : 27017) failed

ComputerName: localhost 
RemoteAddress: ::1
ResolvedAddresses: {::1, 127.0.0.1} 
PingSucceeded: True 
PingReplyDetails: System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply 
TcpClientSocket: 
TcpTestSucceeded: False 
RemotePort: 27017
TraceRoute:  
Detailed: False
InterfaceAlias: Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1 
InterfaceIndex: 1 
InterfaceDescription:  
NetAdapter:  
NetRoute: MSFT_NetRoute (InstanceID = "DD;9;?B55;55DD55;") 
SourceAddress: ::1 
NameResolutionSucceeded: True 
BasicNameResolution: {Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.DnsRecord_AAAA,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.DnsRecord_A} 
LLMNRNetbiosRecords: {} 
DNSOnlyRecords: {Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.DnsRecord_A} 
AllNameResolutionResults: {Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.DnsRecord_AAAA,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.DnsRecord_A} 
IsAdmin: True 
NetworkIsolationContext: Loopback 
MatchingIPsecRules:
```

What am I missing? Is GitHub limiting ports? I couldn't find any documentation on what ports are blocked or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 :**

The issue might be that the connection from client to server is blocked by a firewall. Can you Please check if the relevant GCP firewall setting is enabled for port 27017.
Also , Please check the target tags and update it accordingly if required . This will allow instances tagged with mongodb-instance to accept connections on port 27017.

**Solution 2 :**

As per the below output provided by you, it is observed that PingSucceeded was True. Whereas, the response returned as False for the PingSucceeded. In such cases, it is observed that the ICMP requests might be disabled on the remote server/device.

```
PingSucceeded:       True 
TcpTestSucceeded:    False
```

As you are expecting `Test-NetConnection localhost -port 27017` to succeed,please follow the below steps.

Open PowerShell in the Windows server and type the following command:

```
tnc <ip_address> -port <PortNumber>
```

If the device was having issues where it powered off or it got disconnected from the network, a response like below is expected.

```
PingSucceeded       : False
TCPTestSucceeded    : False
```

If the connection is healthy  (i.e. MongoDb Server is able to successfully connect) then the following response in PowerShell is expected.

```
TcpTestSucceeded    : True
```

The above response tells us specifically that the Port 27017 is open and the Test-NetConnection module was able to validate TCP handshake, so the port should be ready to establish a connection.

The above information is derived from the [link](https://blog.softwaretoolbox.com/using-powershell-for-troubleshooting-tcp-ports) which was drafted by Rodrigo Restrepo

Comment: About solution 1, since I am using an ssh tunnel, shouldn't the only port that matters be 22? And I can guarantee that port 22 is open, as I can ssh into the VM

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. Could you please check solution 2 and confirm if it is useful to you in resolving the issue.

Comment: I actually found a solution/workaround. instead of using a Windows runner on Github I am using a linux runner ( I had to rework my workflow) Some how on Windows the portforwarding is not working.